# SIMcard applets development - hardware recommendations

Tags: javacard, pcsc

I want to develop JavaCard 2.2.x applet, load to developer SIM card. I also need to connect to the SIM card through PCSC-Lite on Ubuntu (because of SEEK-FOR-ANDROID).

However, I don't know what hardware should I buy...I've already bought few (cheap) PC/SC smart card readers from Ebay and so, but there are not recognized by Gemalto Card Manager or any other soft for loading applets to SIMs.

I can't afford to try "real-deal" dev kits, as those are quite expensive for me (...student). I need to be sure before buying any of those. So my question is...

**Would you give me some recommendations which JavaCard Dev kits (Reader + dev SIM card) should I buy? I've read, that ACR38 Dev Kit works nicely with Gemalto Dev Suite but there are no DEV SIM cards in the kit (at least, there are not mentioned in specs).**

Thanks!!

Comment: As long as you don't have access to a testing GSM/UMTS network you don't need the SIM card functionality because a dev SIM card can not be used in any regular mobile network. Therefore you could just use a regular JavaCard without any SIM functionality.

Comment: Ok, so for example, any Omni key reader should work with Gemalto Dev Suite...

Comment: Yes, you're right Robert. Thanks for reply. I really don't need SIM funcionality, my task is just to simulate SIM (university task :)). Problem is, that I can't find any smart card in e-shops, that has version of JC platform in specs...that's why I am asking for recommendations for specific products, so I don't have to buy and try (and spend money) them myself (as I did with card readers :)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly speaking I don't know any cheap kit which includes sample cards except expensive (for students) Gemalto Card Admin and Gemalto Dev Suite.
For the reader I can recommend you Gemalto PCTwin reader, which you can buy online from Gemalto Web store [here](http://boutique.gemalto.com/boutique/GEMALTO-B2CCORP-Site/-/PC-USB-TR/pdu-WFS-en_US-EUR-wrAKAwOEefAAAAEizsko8Cyo-JDQKAwOEVoIAAAElCuseUAux?JumpTo=OfferList&ParcoursTracking=.Home).

At the same time officially Gemalto Dev Suite is not working on Ubuntu and trial version which you can download from Gemalto Dev Network has limitation - you can use only Card Simulator and not real reader. May be it was the reason why you couldn't use your reader as if it is PCSC reader there is no difference for Dev Suite.

What I can propose you as a student - participation to Gemalto SIMAgine contest for students. In this case you'll receive all tools and cards for free.